# Want to spread current cluster data over more and smallere sstables

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1

Our cassandra 2.1.15 application' KS (using STCS) are leveling in less than 100 sstables/node of which some data sstables are now getting into the +1TB size. This means heavy/longer compactions plus longer time before tombstones and their evicted data gets in the same compaction view (application do both create/read/delete of data), thus longer before real disk space gets reclaimed, this sucks :(

Our Application Vendor later revealed to us, that they normally recommend hashing the data over 10-20 CFs in the application KS rather than our currently created 3 CFs, guessing as an way to keep ratio of sstables vs sizes in a 'workable' range. Only the application can't have this changed now we have begun hashing data out in our 3 CFs.

Currently we got 14x linux node cluster, nodes of same HW and size (running w/equal amount of vnodes), originally constructed with two data_file_directories in two xfs FS on each their logical volumes - LVs backed each by a PV (6+1 raid5). Then as some nodes began to compact data skewed in these data dirs/LVs when growning sstable sizes, we merged both data dirs onto one LV and expanded this LV with the thus released PV. So we now got 7x nodes with two data dirs in one LV backed by two PVs and 7x nodes with two data dirs in two LVs on each their PV.

1) Now as sstable sizes keeps growning due to more data and using STCS (as recommend by App Vendor) we're thinking we might be able spread data over more and smallere sstables by simply adding more data dirs in our LVs as compensation for having less CFs rather than adding more HW nodes :) Wouldn't this work to spread data over more and smallere sstables or is the a catch in using multiple data dir compared with fewer?

1) Follow-up: must have had a brain fa.. that day, off course it won't :) The Compaction Strategy doesn't bother with over how many data dirs a CF' sstables  are scattered only bothers with the sstables them selves according to the strategy. So only way to spread over more and smallere sstables *is* to hash data over more CFs. Too bad Vendor did the time-space trade off not to record in which CF a partition key is hashed a long with the key it self, then hashing might have been reseeded to a larger number of CFs. Now only way is to built a new cluster w/more CFs and migrate data there.

2) We could then possibly use either sstablesplit on the largest sstables or removing/rejoining with more than two data dirs node by node to get rit of the currently real big sstables. Would either approach work to get sstable sizes scaled down and which way is most recommendable?

2) Follow-up: well if one node is decommissioned is token range will be scatter to other nodes, specially when using multiple vnodes/node and thus one big sstables would be scatter over more nodes and left to the mercy of the compaction strategy at other nodes. But generally if 1 out of 14 nodes, each with 256 vnodes, would be scattered to the 13 other nodes for sure, right?
Thus only increasing other nodes' amount of data by roughly 1/13 of decommissioned node' content. But rejoining such a node again would properly only send roughly same amount of data back eventually getting compacted into similar sized sstables, meaning we've done a lot IO+streaming for nothing... Unless tombstones were among the original data but just to far apart to be lucky enough to enter same compaction views (small sstable vs large sstable), such an exercise may possible get data shuffled around giving better/other chance to get some tombstone+their data evicted through the scatter+rejoining faster than waiting to strategy to get TS+data in same compaction view, dunno... any thoughs on the value of possible doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Huh that was a huge thought dump.

I'll try to get straight to the point. Using ANY type of raid (except stripe) is a deathtrap. If your nodes don't have sufficient space then you either add disks as JBODs to your nodes or scale out. Second thing is your application creating, deleting, updating and reading data and you are using STCS? And with all that you have 1TB+ per node? I don't even want to get into questioning the performance of that setup.

My suggestion would be to rethink the setup having data size, access patterns, read/write/delete/update ratios and data retention plans in mind. 14 nodes with 1TB+ of data each is not catastrophic (even thou the docu states that going past 600-800GB is bad, its not) but you need to change the approach. LCS works wonders for scenarios like yours and with proper planning you can have that cluster running a long time before having to scale out (or TTL your data) with decent performance.

Comment: Thanks for replying!

Comment: Initial nodes used JBODs, but they got IO hot spotted during compaction which then lacked behind, hence the change to raid5 to activate more spindles per IO, it made compaction being able to keep up back then w/less data. Now it's 5-6TB/node, +80TB in all, w/single sstables getting into the +1-1.5TB size :( App Vendor recommends STCS and no vnodes, but that's based on using v.1.2 testing. You think STCS is bad and that LCS would rather scale out on more and better size-controlled sstables. Can't use TTL as it's the App users who decide when to delete data.

Comment: A lot has changed since 1.2 version. Having raid5 is like throwing away your performance on redundant data redundancy which is handled by database itself. Only raid we use with Cassandra is stripe because of the performance, everything else is redundant.
I would recommend you to check out LCS and even test it on that cluster (you can easily change it while running) and see what are the results. LCS is a bit more IO intensive but for that workload I would recommend it.

Comment: Well I know, but again, comparing our host shared HDS SAN arrays with a shared controller w/+64GB cache that almost always uses raid5 in backends and w/single host and a smartctlr w/2GB cache doing HWraid, one would think... LCS would it be possible to swap back to STCS? Not sure thought about LCS as AppVendor properly wouldn't support it, bit like our vnode usage. They seem not to have data to suggest to got otherwise than STCS.

Comment: Well you asked and I gave you answers based on my knowledge and experience. If you are stuck with that AppVendor then either dump them or face the consequences of their limits and good luck.